# Extend Kie-server in CDI environment

Tags: maven, jbpm, kie

I want to extend Kie-server in a CDI environment (Wildfly 19).

I'm following official doc: https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.45.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_cdi

Currently, I have a jar file containing CDI environment producer class and some CDI beans for initialization. I put this jar inside kie-server\WEB-INF\lib manually.

Is there a way to build a war artifact using maven which extends kie-server? For example an archetype to use where I can package my jar without manual patch of the kie-server war?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone has the same need.

I tried at the beginning jbpm-services-cdi with kie-server war but some services like deploymentService are present twice (CDI bean and kie-server deployment service singleton) which causes problems.

I ended up using kie-server services from ServiceRegistry.
Please note that ExecutorService is registered in ServiceRegistry only after containers are deployed. There is a system property to trigger containers synchronous deployment: org.kie.server. sync.deploy.

Thanks,